# Find current balance of all users and check whether they have breached their credit limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on this question and I appreciate for your help!

[Question in detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfVXB.png)

I will just paste here the query to create tables and add records in them. It might be easier to test.

```
CREATE TABLE user_financial_detail(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
first_name varchar(20),
last_name varchar(20),
vpa VARCHAR(20),
credit_limit int 
);

CREATE TABLE transaction_log(
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
paid_by VARCHAR(20),
paid_to VARCHAR(20),
amount INT,
transacted_on TIMESTAMP 
);

INSERT INTO user_financial_detail VALUES
(1,'shea','caldwell','sc',5000),
(2,'martena','leblanc','ml',10000),
(3,'tashya','riley','tr',25000);

INSERT INTO transaction_log VALUES
(1,'ml','tr',13155,'2019/11/21'),
(2,'tr','ml',10883,'2019/09/10'),
(3,'sc','tr',15012,'2018/12/25'),
(4,'ml','sc',5700,'2018/05/18'),
(5,'tr','sc',18473,'2018/07/02');
```

[Table layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbylb.png)

Comment: What is `vpa`? Is it unique for each user?

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question that’s difficult to answer concisely and is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. Instead of leaving us to speculate on what you might need, give us something to build so we can focus help in those areas where it’s most needed.

Comment: @tadman you are totally right! I did not provide any code because I am super new in sql, so I did not think my code will help :(

Comment: @Eren pls post your question details as text, instead of image. Most users won't click on the image link.

Comment: Any code helps. Thanks for adding some.

Comment: Still new in this community. Learning how things work :) @tadman

Comment: @rohitwats yes, vpa is unique for each user

Comment: Absolutely no problem with learning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find balance for each user:

```
select vpa, sum(total_amount) balance
from (
  select paid_by vpa, sum(-amount) total_amount
  from transaction_log
  group by paid_by
   union all
  select paid_to vpa, sum(amount) total_amount
  from transaction_log
  group by paid_to
) b
group by vpa
```

Then join this result with `user_financial_detail` to get the rest of the data:

```
select 
  concat(u.first_name, ' ',  u.last_name) name, 
  b.vpa, 
  b.balance + u.credit_limit current_balance,
  case
    when b.balance + u.credit_limit >= 0 then 'no'
    else 'yes'
  end credit_limit_breached  
from user_financial_detail u
inner join (
  select vpa, sum(total_amount) balance
  from (
    select paid_by vpa, sum(-amount) total_amount
    from transaction_log
    group by paid_by
     union all
    select paid_to vpa, sum(amount) total_amount
    from transaction_log
    group by paid_to
  ) bi
  group by vpa
) b on b.vpa = u.vpa
```

Result:

```
name              vpa      current_balance    credit_limit_breached
shea caldwell     sc       14161                  no
martena leblanc   ml       2028                   no
tashya riley      tr       23811                  no
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2bf2241f3f3a8090028ad33c82eceeb7)**

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is missing the last part. Maybe the question was not clear. When calculating the current balance, we should do the match between the user_financial_detail table credit_limit column and the current_balance column that are coming from the grouping. Then, we will have the current balance

Comment: @Eren I have modified my answer based on this new information. Please upvote and accept if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT **Concat**(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) NAME,

       b.vpa,

       b.current_balance,

       CASE

         WHEN b.current_balance < 0

              AND *Abs*(b.current_balance) > u.credit_limit THEN "yes"

         ELSE "no"

       END                                    credit_limit_breached

FROM   user_financial_detail u

       INNER JOIN (SELECT vpa,

                          *Sum*(total_amount) current_balance

                   FROM   (SELECT paid_by      vpa,

                                  *Sum*(-amount) total_amount

                           FROM   transaction_log

                           GROUP  BY paid_by

                           UNION ALL

                           SELECT paid_to     vpa,

                                  *Sum*(amount) total_amount

                           FROM   transaction_log

                           GROUP  BY paid_to) bi

                   GROUP  BY vpa) b

               ON b.vpa = u.vpa;

Answer (score 0):

with credit as (select a.vpa,sum(b.amount) as credit from user_financial_detail as a inner join transaction_log as b on a.vpa=b.paid_to group by a.vpa)

, debit as (select a.vpa,sum(b.amount) as debit from user_financial_detail as a inner join transaction_log as b on a.vpa=b.paid_by group by a.vpa)

select a.vpa,(b.credit-c.debit),case
when (b.credit-c.debit)<0 then 'yes'
else 'no'
end
from user_financial_detail as a inner join credit as b on a.vpa=b.vpa inner join debit as c on a.vpa=c.vpa;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).